# Help with solving system of equations over complexes

Tags: nonlinear

Hi can you suggest me a way to Reduce/solve the following equation(analytic/numeric):

```
eqn= {-a1 + I (\[Pi] (((1/2 - I) + \[Pi]/3) Conjugate[
       r1] + ((1/2 + I) + \[Pi]/3) Conjugate[r2]) + 
  3 \[Pi] (((1 - 2 I) + (2 \[Pi])/3) Conjugate[
       r1] + ((1 + 2 I) + (2 \[Pi])/3) Conjugate[r2])) == 0, -a2 + I (\[Pi] (Conjugate[
       r1] ((-I + Sqrt[3]/2)^2 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
     Conjugate[r2] ((I + Sqrt[3]/2)^2 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9])) + 
  3 \[Pi] (Conjugate[
       r1] ((-2 I + Sqrt[3])^2 + 2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
     Conjugate[r2] ((2 I + Sqrt[3])^2 + 2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]))) == 0, C2 (1 - n1) - C0 (1 + n1) - 4 Im[(A a1 + A1 a2) r1] == 0, -C0 (1 + n2) - 4 Im[(a2 B + a1 B1) r2] == 0, -r1 + I n1 Conjugate[A a1 + a2 B1] == 0, -r2 + I n2 Conjugate[a1 A1 + a2 B] == 0};

var={a1, a2, r1, r2, n1, n2};
Simplify[Reduce[eqn, var]];
```

It's running for a long time.
Thanks.

Comment: Break it down.  You can solve for `Conjugate[r1]` and `Conjugate[r2]` from your first two equations.  To go further you will need assumptions for your known variables a1,a2,A1,A1 etc. or input the values if you have them.  I cannot tell if they are real or complex and MMA can't either.

Comment: @BillWatts, Thanks bill. All variables are unknown and complexes except for n1 and n2. Though, I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

[Not a full answer but might all the same be of use.]

An analytic solution might be out of reach. I would suggest as a start the following.

(1) Recast in terms of explicit real variables using `ComplexExpand`.
(2) Convert trig constants to radicals to make algebraic dependencies more obvious.
(3) Clear denominators to obtain explicit polynomials.

These can be done as below.

```
exprs = Numerator[
  Together[ToRadicals[
    Flatten[ComplexExpand[
       ReIm[{-a1 + 
           I (\[Pi] (((1/2 - I) + \[Pi]/3) Conjugate[
                   r1] + ((1/2 + I) + \[Pi]/3) Conjugate[r2]) + 
              3 \[Pi] (((1 - 2 I) + (2 \[Pi])/3) Conjugate[
                   r1] + ((1 + 2 I) + (2 \[Pi])/3) Conjugate[
                   r2])), -a2 + 
           I (\[Pi] (Conjugate[
                   r1] ((-I + Sqrt[3]/2)^2 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
                 Conjugate[
                   r2] ((I + Sqrt[3]/2)^2 + Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9])) + 
              3 \[Pi] (Conjugate[
                   r1] ((-2 I + Sqrt[3])^2 + 2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]) + 
                 Conjugate[
                   r2] ((2 I + Sqrt[3])^2 + 2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]))), 
          C2 (1 - n1) - C0 (1 + n1) - 
           4 Im[(A a1 + A1 a2) r1], -C0 (1 + n2) - 
           4 Im[(a2 B + a1 B1) r2], -r1 + 
           I n1 Conjugate[A a1 + a2 B1], -r2 + 
           I n2 Conjugate[a1 A1 + a2 B]} /. {r1 -> r1re + I*r1im, 
          r2 -> r2re + I*r2im, a1 -> a1re + I*a1im, 
          a2 -> a2re + I*a2im}]]] /. 0 -> Nothing]]]
vars = {a1re, a1im, a2re, a2im, r1re, r1im, r2re, r2im, n1, n2};
```

From here it is straightforward to define a solver that will give numeric output when all parameters are fed explicit numeric values.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will look on to it.